# CollectionFS cfs:dropbox How get url to image after uploading?

Tags: meteor, dropbox, collectionfs, cfs

I published my whole folder with images, but how generate automatically url in my code for each image?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `url` method. From [CollectionFs docs](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#url)

> url
>
> Returns the HTTP file URL for the current FS.File.
>
> Specify a store attribute to get the URL for a specific store. If you
>   don't specify the store name, the URL will be for the copy in the
>   first defined store.

If you use several stores (for example I'm using file store for thumbs and S3 for full images for one collection), then define store or it returns first store url.